# "...glare of the big electric standards that lit.." - meaning of "standard"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, literature

In a A.Blackwood story, I have trouble understanding the following:

> Pedestrians went hurrying and shivering along the pavements,
> disappearing into the gloom of countless ugly little houses the moment
> they passed beyond **the glare of the big electric standards that lit
> the thundering motor-buses in the main street.**

I consulted two dictionaries but could not find a suitable meaning for "standard" that would fit the context here. I am also not sure whether the buses were lit by them or the other way around (the buses lit them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must refer to street lamps. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lamp-standard . It's the buses which are being illuminated by the lamps (otherwise it would be *were lit by the buses*).